# Directional Fields in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am trying to draw a direction field for the differential equation:

> y' = -y(y-3)

The output should look like the photo below:

[image: Direction Field for dydt=-y(y-3)]

I am very confused and everything I have tried has not worked.  Please help and thank you very much!

Comment: what you're looking for is [`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_simple_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-simple-demo-py) (as in the thing that holds arrows) from `matplotlib`

Answer (score 1):

To create a nice looking arrow plot for a differential equation, we need to create a 2d field of direction vectors. Given the image you shared, I'm going to assume `dxdt = 1` (or some other fixed value. This means going for a full 2d graph is not strictly conveying any information over a single vertical line of arrows, but it does help illustrate the passage of `t` along the x axis.

Start by creating a grid of x, y coordinates where to put the arrows:

```
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 5, .25), np.arange(-2, 5, .25))
```

Then calculate `U = dxdt` and `V = dydt` as the direction vector components for each arrow position:

```
U = np.ones_like(X) #dxdt = 1
V = -Y * (Y - 3)
```

You could stop here, and call `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver(X, Y, U, V)` and get a decent plot, but you stated the graph should only show direction, so we must take all these `U,V` vectors, and normalize them to unit length:

```
magnitude = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)
U = U/magnitude
V = V/magnitude
```

Now we plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.quiver(X, Y, U, V)
plt.show()
```